# Should I create an empty $HOME/.vimrc, or copy /etc/vim/vimrc?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to make modifications to `$HOME/.vimrc`, but the file does not exist yet, so I need to create it.

Should I copy `/etc/vim/vimrc` to `$HOME/.vimrc`, and then make my modifications, or should I just create an empty file? Which is the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system-wide `/etc/vim/vimrc` is usually sourced *in addition* to your user's `~/.vimrc`, so you should just put your own customizations into it. Start with a blank file and add any custom settings and mappings.

Only if you intend to share the same `.vimrc` across multiple systems (which may have different global settings), it would be best to add those settings to your personal file, or to turn off / undo the global settings (should you not like them).

Answer (score 0):

A better idea would be to copy `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim` as a starting point fro your own vimrc file.  Personally, I start my vimrc file with

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

although there are arguments against this practice.  If you already have an idea about what you want to customize, then you probably know enough to copy selected parts from the example vimrc file.

Comment: But that contradicts Ingo's answer, he says "/etc/vim/vimrc is usually sourced in addition to your user's ~/.vimrc". So according to him, there's no need for that. Or is he wrong?

Comment: Where is the contradiction?  Probably `$VIMRUNTIME` is not `/etc/vim` and `vimrc_example.vim` is certainly not `vim`, so we are talking about two different files.  A system vimrc may come from a system administrator (if you are one user on a multi-user system) or from a package maintainer (such as MacVim or Debian or Red Hat).  Ingo is correct that it will be `source`d:  see `:help startup` for details.  The file I am talking about is part of the standard vim distribution, and is intended as a starting point for your personal vimrc file.